# How to add JPanel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm fairly new to swing, so I'm not sure how a lot of this works. I'm trying to add a JPanel into a JFrame. Just to get a feel for the basics, I'm just printing a horizontal line and the text "Hello World" on top.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GUI extends JFrame{
    
    public GUI() {
        setTitle("Frame");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);    
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawLine(0, 250, 500, 250);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI g = new GUI();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        panel.setSize(500, 500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        label.setText("Hello World");
        label.setForeground(Color.green);
        panel.add(label);
        g.add(panel);

    }

}
```

For some reason, I can't get the JPanel to display.

Comment: 1) `setVisible(true);` should be called on a frame after all components are added, and `pack()` is called. 2) `public void paint(Graphics g) {` Custom painting should that be done in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of a `JPanel` rather than in the `JFrame` (for multiple reasons, but also here because the panel will cover any custom painting in the frame).

Comment: Oracle has a helpful[ tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  Spending three weeks or more going through each section and studying each code example would be a beneficial way to spend your study time.

Comment: See [here](https://ideone.com/eTkkvL) a better-structured version of your code